# Angular Material DropDown Accept value in number datatype

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am creating an application by using angular-material.

In my application, it will have a dropdpown. I am using *ngFor the data from backend mircoservice. However, the backend return value with number datatype and angular-material only accept string value.

Any solution how to enable angular-material accept number datatype as value?

The following is my source code.

html

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
        {{food.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Sample JSON from microservice

```
 [
    {value: 0, viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 1, viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 2, viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ]
```

I understand that I can parse to convert number datatype from backend and convert to string to display purpose. And I need to convert the string back to number datatype when I PUT to microservice.

However, after I click save button. It fail to binding my selected data because I have converted it to number datatype when I click save button.

Any solution to solve this issue.

Comment: It seems to work with numbers (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tl11xh)). Make sure that you define `selectedValue` as a number.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz to reproduce an issue?